# Python3 printing after script finishes instead of when function done doing stuff

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have made a script which is executed locally and doing some remote stuff
ex: ssh  python3 myscript

Script itself have few functions which prints whatever they done
for example at one state i use to enable some services i.e. systemctl enable... then prints if its enabled or not

The problem i got:

when i run it like: `ssh <ip> python3 myscript`

## output should be:

```
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable nginx 
Nginx was enabled (Thats my print)
3 Nov 18:45:00 ntpdate[2312]: adjust time server 132.163.96.2 offset -0.00231 sec
ntp time synced by: 0.europe.pool.ntp.org (also my print from sync_ntp func)
```

## but the actual output is:

```
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable nginx
*no print*
3 Nov 18:45:00 ntpdate[2312]: adjust time server 132.163.96.2 offset -0.00231 sec
*no print*
when script finish i got the prints:
Nginx was enabled
ntp time synced by: 0.europe.pool.ntp.org
```

```
def enable_nginx():
    nginx = subprocess.Popen(['bash', 'systemctl', 'enable', 'nginx'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    if nginx.wait() == 0: # i.e. OK
        print("Nginx enabled")
    else:
        print("Nginx failed")
```

```
def sync_ntp():
    ntpdate = subprocess.Popen(['ntpdate', '0.europe.pool.ntp.org'])
    if ntpdate.wait() == 0:
        print("Time synced by: 0.europe.pool.ntp.org")
    else:
        print("Cannot sync time")
```

Above is my little function snippet

So i dont get why prints come last, when it should print right after it enables nginx, but instead it prints everything at the bottom..

Comment: Hey, just some feedback on your question. It would improve your question if you could provide a bit more clarity about your exact code and setup instead of talking in generic terms ("doing stuff", "prints whatever", etc). If you can provide us with a minimalist example of what you are trying to accomplish and your example it would make your question more readable and improve your chances of getting good quality answers.

Comment: Your question is vague so it's hard to see what you actually want or what's going wrong, but it sounds like you're expecting `subprocess.call` to somehow be run asynchronously?

Comment: @ApplePie sure, i am new to this community so excuse me please, i did edit to my question i guess it looks a bit clearer than before

Comment: @RandomDavis i dont expect sub.call to run asynchronously, i expect when i execute certain function for example sync_ntp, to get the output of sync_ntp after it finishes executing, not after the whole script finishes (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

In a function, use the `return` command and not the `print` command.

Comment: Tried, changed print with return, same, the output comes after the whole script finishes, not after function get executed